# security for some users to only read the record which is active (flag 1 or latest date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-level-security

In a DataWarehouse (SQL Server 2012) and for some table(s) I want to implement an option where some users can only see the latest row (date or flag) instead of the whole history. Is this possible?

Comment: Create view with you conditionals

Answer (score 0):

VIEWs would be a good use case for this... something like this using a window function to find the "latest" record. You could also use `MAX()` on the `dateColumn` with an inner join. Just fill in the partition section `<column1, column2>` for what ever you want to group your data by. [Here's the docs on this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
create view myView
as

;with cte as(
select
   primaryKey
   ,column2
   ,dateColumn
   ,RN = row_number over (partition by <column1, column2> order by dateColumn desc)
from
   YourTable)

select 
   primaryKey
   ,column2
   ,dateColumn
from cte
where RN = 1
```

Then, for the users you want to only see this data... you'd explicitly grant them view.

```
grant select on myView to MyUserGroup
```